# Escaping special characters for SQL Server CE in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, escaping

I am using an old webservice that has some issues handling special characters, specifically the apostrophe `'` and brackets `[]`. My intended work-around is to simply escape characters before sending them to the webservice, but is there a built-in function in the C# standard library or the SQL Server Compact Edition libraries that will do this for me?

I know this is not the optimal solution, but I can't wait for the webservice to get fixed and I don't have direct access to do paramterized queries or similar. I'd also like to avoid writing my only string escape function since a ton of things can go wrong or get missed.

```
String escaped = Obj.some_escape_function(original_string);
```

Comment: try using regex in c# it is the best way

Answer (score 0):

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

you can use regular expressions to remove special characters.

```
public string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for insert/update (msaccess, mysql, mssql), It's possible that for a specific DDBB can be optimized.

```
public static class Obj
{
  //....
  public static string FtCad(string ci)
  {
    return Regex.Replace(ci, @"[\r\n\\'""]", @"\$0");
  }

}

//And when need:
string fieldcad = Obj.FtCad(Text1.text);
```